# Tools to profile the most computational cost of my .NET application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# application which sometimes cost the CPU very high. I want to see which part of the code cost most. But the Microsoft CLR Profiler only determins the memory usage, it's not meant for computational profiling according to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLR_Profiler). Is there any tools to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the RedGate Ants Performance Profiler. It's a commercial product but worth the money.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question - [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Redgate ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm), they have a free trial available.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working for a big company, you could put in a request for the Team Edition. It contains really cool time profilers.(I hear its available in Professional edition in 2010, but I work with VS 2008)